# Comment comprendre le sens de cette phrase ?

Tags: verbes, adverbes, littérature

On trouve sur la toute première page de « La Horde du Contrevent » (dont le PDF vous pouvez trouver, d’ailleurs, [ici](https://flipbook.cantook.net/?d=%2F%2Fedenlivres.fr%2Fflipbook%2Fpublications%2F22988.js&oid=320&c=&m=&l=&r=&f=epub)) la phrase suivante :

> Le vent sabla cru le village à travers les jointures béantes du granit

J’ai du mal à comprendre son sens. Il est où le verbe ? « Sabla » ? Dans ce cas cru serait un adverbe, mais je ne trouve pas son sens dans le dico. « Cru » ? Dans ce cas « sabla » serait soit un adverbe soit un adjectif, mais je ne trouve pas non plus son sens dans le dico. Et ce « cru » serait du verbe « croire » ou « croître »? Aucun des deux n’a de sens si j’ai bien compris le texte.
Aidez-moi à me débrouiller s’il vous plaît.

Comment: sabler doucement/sabler cru

Comment: Vous avez raison de vous interroger, car ici, effectivement, l'adjectif "cru" est employé en tant qu'adverbe, et c'est sans doute ce qui vous a troublé. il s'agit en théorie d'une faute de langage, mais malheureusement ce procédé est devenu très courant depuis une vingtaine d'années. Un jeune homme dira facilement " je m'ennuie grave ici" au lieu de "je m'ennuie gravement". A terme, la distinction entre adjectif et adverbe est menacée, et c'est bien dommage.

Comment: @BBBreiz Voui, *on lrekonê pudutou, lfransé, amésa pudutou*...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oui, le verbe est *sabler* qui, ici, veut dire « couvrir de sable ».

*Cru* est un adjectif. Cet adjectif peut avoir plusieurs sens (Cru dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cru#Adjectif)). Ici ça veut dire « sans ménagement », « de façon violente ». Mais on peut dire qu'ici il joue un rôle d'adverbe vu qu'il modifie le verbe.

C'est fréquent, possible et correct, d'employer en français un adjectif comme adverbe. Extrait du *Bon usage*<sup>1</sup> :

> Un bon nombre d'adjectifs s’emploient adverbialement après certains verbes : ils restent alors invariables (...). Dans l'usage ordinaire, ce sont surtout des adjectifs courts et très usuels qui s'emploient ainsi, et le plus souvent dans des expressions consacrées comme *voir clair*, *parler haut*, *chanter juste*, etc. Mais la langue littéraire a fait de ce genre de construction un emploi fort large et parfois fort hardi : *La multitude voit bête* (Flaubert, *L'éducation sentimentale*) — *Des feux de joie qui flambent rouge* (Pierre Loti, *Vers Hispahan*) — *Je défiais les défenseurs de la prohibition de nommer six États qui voteraient humide* (André Maurois, *Chantiers américains*)...

Il s'agit donc dans le cas présent d'un emploi très littéraire,  tout est soigneusement recherché dans cette phrase, de l'emploi de « sabla » là ou un auteur lambda aurait dit « couvrit de sable » à cet emploi de « cru », rare dans ce sens. Ce qui n'étonne guère de la part de l'auteur (Alain Damasio), dont le style a souvent été remarqué, et en particulier pour ce roman<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition.

<sup>2</sup> Pour ne citer qu'une seule critique, je reprendrai une partie de celle du magazine *Futura Sciences* « De cette écriture déroutante, certains parlent [de *La Horde du Contrevent*] comme d'une expérience littéraire rare, d'un récit poétique à couper le souffle quand d'autres saluent la qualité d'écriture d'un grand récit français [...] voici un livre exigeant, riche et complexe, qui ne ressemble à aucun autre. »</sup>